# Should this question be protected?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, protected-questions

I saw that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object) question was [protected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) and the accepted answer referred to another older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) which wasn't.

At a minimum, shouldn't the older one be protected as well?

Also, shouldn't the newer one be possibly marked as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)? While they differ at a first glance, they are really talking about the same thing. The biggest reason I am doubting the dupe flag is because the older post is more of a copy/paste from docs.

Comment: Why does it need to be protected?

Comment: I take it that protection is added on a need basis?

Comment: Typically questions are protected to prevent low rep users from spamming posts, I don't actually understand why the first one is protected. And the second one isn't attracting noisy answers so it doesn't seem to need it either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see either of those questions needing protection right now.  Their history doesn't indicate that they warrant protection; there were no poor answers from low rep participants on either of them (the first one doesn't even have a deleted answer on it!).

I've removed the protection.  If it warrants it, then we can add it back later.